# Angular testing wrong url in order to call error callback and test it

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I want to test an HTTP post error callback. In fact I have this code:

```
 $http.post(url, $.param(postData)).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
              if (data == "ok") {
                  $(location).attr('href', '#/repositories');

              } else {
                  $scope.msg=gettext("Enter valid username and password");                      
              }
              // data - response from server
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.msg=gettext("Check Settings");               
          });
```

I used httpbackend to test success calback like this :

```
 it("login url passed",function(){
        httpBackend.expectPOST(myurl).respond(data); // response simulation
        httpBackend.flush();
  }
```

With the good url and data, but i want to test a wrong URL so callback error will be executed. Unfortunately, when i use a wrong URL the test fails and the callback URL is not called.

Can you help me to test with a wrong URL?

Comment: Did you try with jasmine syntax `spyOn(object, method).andCallThrough()` [jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>andCallThrough</code>) ?

Comment: i don't see how can i use it with wrong post url !!!